# Redux store updated but component is not updating

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Like in title, component EventList is not re-rendered when redux state is updated. I think I've tried everything, but nothing works. That the state is modified I can see in the browser extension Redux DevTools.

Please, write what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you in advance for help.

EventList component:

```
    interface RootState {
      lastEvent: Event,
      allEvents: Event[]
    }

    const EventList = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const lastEvent = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.lastEvent);
    var allEvents = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.allEvents);
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(eventActions.getAllEvents());
    }, [lastEvent]);

    return (
      <div>
        {allEvents && <div>EventListTable...</div>}
      </div>
    );};
```

Action:

```
    const getAllEvents = (): ThunkAction<
  void,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
> => (dispatch) => {
 eventService.getAllEvents().then((events: Event[]) => {
    dispatch(success(events));
  });

  function success(events: Event[]): EventActionsTypes {
      return {
        type: GET_ALL_EVENTS,
        events: events,
      };
  }
};
```

Reducer:

```
export interface EventState {
  lastEvent: Event | null;
  allEvents: Event[];
}

const initialState: EventState = {
  lastEvent: null,
  allEvents: [],
};

export function eventReducer(state = initialState, action: EventActionsTypes) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_EVENT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        lastEvent: action.event,
      };
    }
    case GET_ALL_EVENTS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        allEvents: [...action.events],
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Combined all reducers:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authentication,
    registration,
    eventReducer,
    alert,

});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var allEvents = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.eventReducer .allEvents);
```

In redux devtools you can see where `allEvents` is set, why would you try and get it from `state.allEvents`

[Here](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) you can see how combineReducers work and what state it will produce.

Comment: Ok, it works and explain a lot. When I was writing the EventList component, I was following https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-useselector-hook.I thought the RootState interface was declared in the component. But it is not.